# How to Record a Video with Webcam and Save to Server Using RubyOnRails

Tags: html, flash, ruby-on-rails-3.2, webcam, video-recording

I want to record user Video with Webcam and save the recorded video to Server, using Ruby On Rails, which should work in all browsers .I have tried the below approaches, which did not solve my problem.

1. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/ - tried and not able to play / save the recorded video
2. http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ - verified and does not seem to support video recording.
3. http://nimbb.com/ - is a paid one

Please let me know, if any body has a standard solution for this (which works in All / Most of the browsers, preferably an open source).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hey! Did you get an answer? I am struggling with the same problem..

Comment: No Peeyush!! still couldn't find a stable solution.

Comment: See my answer for a detailed analysis of the article's solutions but others as well @Peeyush

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty old question, but just came across it and thought I would at least offer a solution to all future visitors who stumble across this question:

The [MediaStreamRecorder API](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc-20111004.html#mediastreamrecorder) is [currently unimplemented in chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113676), however some users have found [alternative ways](http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/31486670538/creating-webm-video-from-getusermedia) to get it working by stitching together `.webp` images into a `.webm` video. Now, it might not be the best idea to use that experiment, but other projects have taken that idea a lot farther by implementing a cross platform library that implements that idea (and other browser specific solution) of which the first is aptly called [MediaStreamRecorder](https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder). Another option is [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC) which I have used myself in the past of which one advantage is that they have some [specific server side Ruby code](https://github.com/cbetta/record-rtc-experiment) to get it working neatly (not that you need it if you want to do a simple upload, but sometimes you might want to do more than that).

Answer (score 0):

Recording video in the browser is mostly a client side affair so the fact that you're using Ruby server side will not impact the solution.

The only solution that works consistently across desktop and mobile browsers would be one that implements the following:

- desktop: a Flash video recording client + media server
- mobile: `HTML Media Capture`

Some notes on your links:

1. The [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) article mentions the `HTML Media Capture` draft/standard  which only works on mobile browsers
2. The jQuery webcam plugin uses Flash to access the webcam but it can't record video (it doesn't connect to a media server)
3. Commercial **hosted** solutions include [nimbb](http://nimbb.com/), [Pipe](https://addpipe.com/) and [ziggeo](http://ziggeo.com/)
4. Commercial **self hosted** solutions include [HDFVR](https://hdfvr.com/) ([which supports Ruby](http://nusofthq.com/forum/index.php?/topic/2070-rails-wowza-hdfvr/))